# Find most occurence element in array without using php Built-In function

Tags: php

How i can find the most occurrence element in given array
Array can be even or odd
I have found the answer using php built-in function but i want to do this by custom function. Please help...

Comment: I won't ask now why you don't want to use php build-in functions, but you would have to shows us your attempts for your custom function, so that we can help you

Comment: This looks more like a specification than a question. **This site is not called GetYourFreeCodeHere.com**

Comment: i dont want to use built-in function because this question asked by me in interview

Comment: What if two values occur the same number of times?

Comment: the function return only one if there are two most occurrence value

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

    $array = array(1,1,1,4,3,1,3);

    $count_special= array_count_values_special($array);//Counts the values in the array, returns associatve array
    $count= array_count_values($array); //PHP Built in functionCounts the values in the array, returns associatve array

    asort($count_special);
    asort($count);
    print_r($count_special);
    print_r($count);

    function array_count_values_special($array) {
        $ret_array = array();
        foreach($array as $value) {
            foreach($ret_array as $key2 => $value2) {
                if($key2 == $value) {
                    $ret_array[$key2]++;
                    continue 2;
                }
            }
            $ret_array[$value] = 1;
        }
        return $ret_array;
    }
```

enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are referring to by "can be even or odd", but is a function like this what you were looking for?

I don't know the runtime for looking up an object in a PHP array, if it works like a Java hashmap then every lookup would cost O(1).

This + the foreach loop going through your array would be in total O(n). I don't think a builtin PHP function could be faster than that, assuming I'm correct in how a PHP associative array works under the hood.

```
public function mostOccuranceInArray($array)
    {
        // create associative array where key => object value => num of occurances
        $occurancesArray = array();
        $maxOccurances = - 1;
        $mostFrequentVal = NULL;

        foreach ($array as $val) {

            if (! $occurancesArray[$val]) { // if we have not added this value yet
                $occurancesArray[$val] = 0;
            } else {
                $occurancesArray[$val] ++; // increment the number of occurances

                if ($occurancesArray[$val] > $maxOccurances) {
                    $maxOccurances = $occurancesArray[$val];
                    $mostFrequentVal = $val;
                }
            }
        }

        return $val;
    }
```

Comment: even or odd means the array total elements may be even or odd

Comment: iterating to the end of the array using foreach($array as $val) or for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++) will work for iterating over all elements, doesn't matter if the size of the array is even or odd.

Comment: thank you all i got my answer here :) http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/php-array-mode-function

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a function that return an array of the most occurring value(s):

```
var_dump(mostOccurringInArray(array(1,1,1,4,3,1,3,4,3,4,4))); 
// array(2) { [4]=> int(4) [1]=> int(4) }
var_dump(mostOccurringInArray(array(1,1,1,4,3,1,3,4,3))); 
// array(1) { [1]=> int(4) }

function mostOccurringInArray($array) {
    $occurrences = array();
    foreach($array as $v) 
        !array_key_exists($v, $occurrences) ? $occurrences[$v] = 1 : $occurrences[$v]++;    
    asort($occurrences); 
    $max = end($occurrences); 
    return array_filter($occurrences, function($value) use(&$max) { return $value == $max; });
}
```

If you just want to return one single value:

```
function mostOccurringInArray($array) {
    $occurrences = array();
    foreach($array as $v) 
        !array_key_exists($v, $occurrences) ? $occurrences[$v] = 1 : $occurrences[$v]++;    
    asort($occurrences); 
    end($occurrences); 
    return key($occurrences);
}
```